# IE gets wrong Security Zone when accessing SSRS Reports

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, kerberos, security-zone

I have some machines that when accessing SSRS Reports show `Internet` or `Unknown Zone(Mixed)` instead of `Local Intranet`. Some user never report this problem, for others it appears consistent. These machines should be all setup the same. We access the `SSRS` reports with a url like `http://test-intranet.example.com`. Have checked the security settings on the `IE` and that should consider all `*.example.com` pages as `local intranet`.
Very annoying this issue, anybody having a clue what component doesn't play well here ?

Answer (score 0):

In the IE connection settings do all of your machines ignore local proxy server for the address you mentioned.

Assuming it's internal, and assuming you have a proxy, then there should be no need going to the proxy for internal addresses.

Comment: These settings are given to all clients through policies and they are set up that all urls that end with xxx.com are excluded from being sent through the proxy. I could get a bit closer to the cause meanwhile. It seems to be related with the token size of the user. We have it only with users that have a token that is >8k. Still frustrating to hit such issues in 2009 with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Kerberos Token Size hot fix ([KB327825](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327825)) to the machines (desktops and servers)?  You'll also want to roll out the registry setting via a script or [GPO (kb938118)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938118).